# tableHeaderView doesn't properly resize

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cgrectmake

I am using a `UITableView` with a custom `tableHeaderView`

In my `viewDidLayoutSubviews` I  am using properly working code like this:

```
 let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    imageSliderVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.width)
    layerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.width, bounds.width)

    noButton = constructNopeButton()
    yesButton = constructLikedButton()
    buttonOptionsApply()

    nameLbl.frame = CGRectMake(20, layerView.frame.maxY + 20, bounds.width-40, 20)
    nameLbl.makeNameLabelFormat()
    hashtagLbl.frame = CGRectMake(20, nameLbl.frame.maxY + 5, bounds.width-40, layerView.frame.width/3.66)
    hashtagLbl.makeHashtagFormat()

    seperatorLbl.frame = CGRectMake(20, hashtagLbl.frame.maxY + 15, bounds.width-40, 1)

    groupsLbl.frame = CGRectMake(20, seperatorLbl.frame.maxY + 15, 30, 20)
    groupsLbl.makeNameLabelFormat()
    groupsLbl.sizeToFit()
    groupsCountLbl.frame = CGRectMake(groupsLbl.frame.maxX + 5, seperatorLbl.frame.maxY + 15 , 40, 20)
    groupsCountLbl.sizeToFit()

    headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.width, groupsCountLbl.frame.maxY)
    table.tableHeaderView = headerView
```

Without using the headerView everything aligns nicely. 
the table is used with autoLayout - pinning the table to all the edges.

Any idea why this is happening? tried using

```
        headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

it aligns everything to the left top edge.

**edit:**
The views are set like as they are put in storyboard

**edit2: Screenshots**

it is supposed to look like this:

[image]

This is what it looks like

[image]

Comment: What is the output? show the screenshot.

Comment: can you post your viewForHeaderInSection method?

Comment: I didn't use this method. I will have a look at it. What does it supposed to look like in my example?

Comment: Well, your question is about header, and i think that you are subclassing a view and add your custom behavior but, maybe this is not the case, so you can post your viewController code in order to try help?

Answer (score 0):

You can set table hader view in UITableViewDelegate method `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`. And, of course, use NSLayoutConstraint's to locate you elements ([good tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110393/auto-layout-visual-format-language-tutorial)).